# A way to backup or clone a entire Electron/Node.js project

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-forge

It's been quite a long while since I last developed a electron/node.js app. Recently, I wanted to start updating the app with the new version of the 'electron-forge' framework, but I do want to backup the entire project before I start modifying the app. My app is not uploaded to any sources such as GitHub, BitBucket, S3 etc, and all is done on a typical Windows desktop.

Is there a way how I can backup the project before I get get started modifying the app? Can I just ZIP the entire thing?

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](https://github.com/) is the best option. You can revert back to commits as needed. If you need to though, you c an just make a copy of the project on your computer, no need to have it zipped. It is the easiest compared to GitHub, and probably more reliable.